# Empty the textcontent between the tags in xml

Tags: java, regex, xml

I tried to parse below xml using the dom parser. Error is thrown while parsing the xml. That is because some of the special characters are present inside cdata tag of 'b' element. We need only text content of c and e elements. So I am trying to do empty of 'b' element and to use indexof function to get text content of both c and e elements.

```
   <a><b><![CDATA[userinput]]></b><c>text of c</c><d></d><e>text of e</e></a>
```

Below is the code using for pattern matching

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<b>.*?</b>", Pattern.DOTALL |  Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int lastIndex = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    builder.append(input.substring(lastIndex, matcher.start()));
    lastIndex = matcher.end();
}
builder.append(input.substring(lastIndex));
```

Below scenerio is failing with above pattern

```
 <a><b><![CDATA[test 123 </b><c>inside</c>]]></b><c>outside</c><d></d><e>out side</e></a>
```

O/P:-

```
 <a><c>inside</c>]></b><c>outside</c><d></d><e>out side</e></a>
```

Expected :-

```
<a><c>outside</c><d></d><e>out side</e></a>
```

Could you please let me know the best way to resolve this issue. User input might be any choice of text from the user.

Thanks in advance
Gajendra

Comment: You have just provided an excellent case for why you should ***not*** use regex to "parse" XML! Instead, you should address your root problem... why "special characters ... inside cdata tag of 'b' element" cause things to break. Can you provide an example of *that*?

Comment: The best scenario is to match comment like data (ie. CDATA) so it does not affect the matching of `c` and `e` elements.

Comment: Starting I identified below error and cleared with replace all function to remove control characters. 'An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x3) was found in the CDATA section'. Then now I am facing a below error 'The character sequence "]]>" must not appear in content unless used to mark the end of a CDATA section'. Hence I am trying to empty the b element

Comment: The error you get from the dom is because the _CDATA_ is not in the proper form, it should be `<![CDATA[test 123 </b><c>inside</c>]]>`

Comment: Where are you getting this XML from? You say it's user input, but how are they inputting it?

Comment: Yes, @sln you are correct. I missed the missing closing bracket. Unicode `0x03` is the "end of text" character ... it's thinking the entire rest of the XML document is inside the CDATA section.

Comment: We are passing an request to other system to get user input for each problem what they have entered BufferedReader in = null; in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
   while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response = response + decodedString;
   } Response in the form of xml. User enters the input in JSP page.

Comment: Why are you playing around with CDATA ? Are you trying to _remove_ elements with cdata, or are you trying to match `e` and `c` elements? If you just need e and c, you don't have to remove any other stuff to get it.

Comment: This regex will find `e` or `c` content. If group 1 (tag name) is not NULL, then group 2 contains the content. `"(?s)(?><(?:!(?:(?:\\[CDATA\\[.*?\\]\\])|(?:--.*?--)))>)|(?><(?:(?<TagName>[ec](?!\\w))(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+)>)(?<!/>)(?<EorC_content>(?:(?!<(?:[\\w:]+(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+)>|(?><(?:!(?:(?:\\[CDATA\\[.*?\\]\\])|(?:--.*?--)))>)).)*?(?:(?><(?:(?!\\1)[\\w:]+(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+)>|(?><(?:!(?:(?:\\[CDATA\\[.*?\\]\\])|(?:--.*?--)))>))(?:(?!<(?:[\\w:]+(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+)>|(?><(?:!(?:(?:\\[CDATA\\[.*?\\]\\])|(?:--.*?--)))>)).)*?)*?)(?:(?><(?:/\\1\\s*)>))"`

Comment: I am trying to remove only b element in case if it is not possible by regex

Comment: So the user is ... entering XML in a JSP? Really? Also, have you confirmed that if the CDATA looks like `<!CDATA[blah blah </b>]]>` (with two closing square brackts) then you can parse the XML? You just have to be sure the user content doesn't contain `]]>`... sanitize the input for that.

Comment: Yes. Some users are entering xml in text area of JSP. Actually we are sending request in xml format to other system with problem id. They will send response which has user inputs. User input might be anything like xml, json,normal text etc. If user is entered the xml in text area because of some special characters it is failing to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("<b>.*</b>", "");
```

Comment: Below scenerio it will fail :- <a><b><![CDATA[test 123 </b><c>inside</c>]></b><c>outside</c><d></d><e>out side</e><f></b></f></a>.

Comment: This case is a malformed XML. You have a close tag of b whitout open tag. Which output do you expected?